# Не выводится картинка с Django

Tags: python, html, sql, django, html5

[image: Вот код в Html5]

Не выводится картинка

> [Цитата][2]

Ссылка на исходник проекта , скачивайте и смотрите :)
[2]: https://github.com/FANDIM-wolf/Djnago-projects/blob/main/source%20AuthPath/authpath0.2.zip

Comment: Если что пишите на " https://vk.com/m.shishov99"

Comment: Добавьте код своей вьюхи, который рендерит этот template.

Comment: [Как задать хороший вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Замените у img href на src